# How do I make a progress dialog appear while loading a new view with several programatically created views?

Tags: android, progressdialog

So I've looked around quite a bit and it seems that if I want to make a loading indicator of some sort I need to use an AsyncTask. However, an ASyncTask seems to be more suited for fetching or inserting data. In my case, the activity I am loading has a lot of custom views that are programatically generated. In other words, it's all UI activity - so I can't use ASyncTask because I can't run my processes in the background. I want to show a progress dialog so the user knows the new activity is being loaded instead of just looking at a black screen. Anyone know of a way to do this?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // start the progress dialog here

  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    // generate some textviews...
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("textview # " + i);
  }

  // dismiss the progress dialog
```

}

Comment: Oh Sorry, then maybe splash screen solution is not works for you. Your custom views maybe heaviest then my expectation. Allow me to delete my answer, as it is not an solution to you.

Answer (score 7):

//Initialize the progress bar first

```
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progressDialog.setProgress(0);
```

//Display progress bar on updatePreUi()

```
progressDialog.show();
```

//close progress bar on updatePostUi()

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler h=new Handler();  
  ShowProgressDialog();  
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                      h.post(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
                                  {
                                                // generate some textviews...
                                                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                                                 tv.setText("textview # " + i);
                                   }
                                   dismissProgressdialog();

                                }
                            });


                    }
                }).start();
```

Comment: I thought this would be the one, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. The screen still goes black when loading the activity and takes a few seconds to load. It doesn't even show the progress dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can in your layout for the Setting activity use two superposed layouts and then in the activity set Content View with the top layout and add the dynamic views to the layout behind and when finished just set the visibility of the layout on top to gone.

Comment: Couldn't get this solution to work for me... The screen still stays black until all of the views load.

Comment: The dynamic views should be loaded in postExecute in an AsyncTask